# Laravel QueryBuilder to DB::select

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've got an issue with a bottleneck in Laravel eloquent. When running the logic to build the query it's very quick and simple while using eloquent, however, when it finally comes to use `$query->get()` (due to the number of rows, and the number of relational rows), it grinds to a halt and hits `max execution time`. I obviously don't want to just increase the time... And I'd prefer not to re-write all my functions to use raw queries (although I will, if I have to).

My question is, is there a way to pass a `QueryBuilder` sql command to `DB::select` or `DB::raw`.

I know you can use `$query->toSql()` - but I'm lacking the data bound values, if I could get those, I could solve this in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get bindings from a query builder by calling **$query->getBindings()**.

Comment: How are you building the query? Are you using your model class or using DB facade directly?

Comment: You're right. Genius! Thank you :) Due to it's complexity, I was using eloquent due to all of the 'extra' relations I required and it hitting many tables. Just made sense. But with actual data, we're talking millions of rows, I noticed the bottleneck when it was creating models at > 25k rows. So knew that I didn't want models and just the raw query, but obviously didn't want to re-write everything. You're a star!