# Union using With in Laravel / Lumen

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

I'm trying to make an union, for example:

```
$first = Content::selectRaw("id, title, channel_id, description")
->with('trailer')
->where('description', 'asdadadadaid');

$second = OtherTypeOfContent::selectRaw("id, title, channel_id, description")
->with('trailer')
->where('description', 'asdadadadaid');

$data = $first->union($second)->get();
```

For Content, trailer is associated to the table contents_trailers. For OtherTypeOfContent, trailer is associated to the table othertypeofcontent_trailers.

When I try to make the union between this two queries I get always the values of contents_trailers for the with->('trailer'), also for results of the second query. It seems that is taking relations only from the first query.

How can I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: When ever I work with complex SQL queries in Eloquent that are producing results that appear wrong to me, I find it helpful to use the Builder::toSql() method to get the SQL that Eloquent intends to run so I can try and debug it. In your case, try outputting `$first->union($second)->toSql();` and see if the SQL that's returned matches your expectation. Additionally you can add the output to your question for more context.

Comment: Hi xjstratedgebx! Sure, I tested that but the with->('xxxx') part never gets printed in the ->toSql() output in any query. Give it a try and you'll see that.

Comment: Hmmm, so you're not seeing any joins in the complete query? What kind of relationship is trailer set up as? Can you post the resulting query and your Model setups (excluding any sensitive details, of course)?

Comment: I just posted an example because I have a large query but this is my relation for example from Content class: public function trailer() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Trailer', 'contents_trailers''); }. When I try to get results without union, in both cases I get the results OK.

Comment: This is what I said: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676868/laravel-query-tosql-loses-relation-extras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that Eloquent doesn't run any attached `with()` instructions with the core query, but instead selects the rows desired, and then runs a query for each `with()` instruction to get any additional data you needed. That explains why calling `toSQL()` on a query builder with `with()` instructions returns no joins - it won't run them in that query.

So while I fear using `with()` for your union won't work, you can manually build joins into your query. This is what I've done in the past with unions and it's why I thought at first that `toSql()` would return the joins.

Here's an example of a union with joins that I have been using in one of my platforms for a while and it's working well:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Example extends Model
{
    /**
     * Unions the query contained within with the query returned from
     * buildGloballyScopedCampaignsQuery
     */
    public static function findScopedToChannelId($channel_id)
    {
        $first = static::buildGloballyScopedCampaignsQuery();

        return static::select('ac.*')
            ->from('ad_campaigns AS ac')
            ->join('ad_campaign_scopes AS acs', function ($join) use ($channel_id) {
                $join->on('ac.id', '=', 'acs.campaign_id')
                    ->where('acs.channel_id', '=', $channel_id);
            })
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->whereNull('ac.start_date')
                    ->orWhere('ac.start_date', '<', DB::raw('NOW()'));
            })
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->whereNull('ac.end_date')
                    ->orWhere('ac.end_date', '>', DB::raw('NOW()'));
            })
            ->union($first)
            ->orderBy('rank', 'DESC')
            ->get();
    }

    public static function buildGloballyScopedCampaignsQuery()
    {
        return static::select('ac.*')
            ->from('ad_campaigns AS ac')
            ->leftJoin('ad_campaign_scopes AS acs', 'ac.id', '=', 'acs.campaign_id')
            ->whereNull('acs.id')
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->whereNull('ac.start_date')
                    ->orWhere('ac.start_date', '<', DB::raw('NOW()'));
            })
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->whereNull('ac.end_date')
                    ->orWhere('ac.end_date', '>', DB::raw('NOW()'));
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, so... I think Eloquent is really limited.

Comment: Yeah, it does a pretty good job of taking the situations you're going to spend most of your time dealing with and making those generally pretty easy and straight forward. Go a little out of the box, though, and things can start to get syntactically pretty ugly pretty quick.